# VBS in HTA Do and Loop

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have the below VB which works but I would like it to work in a HTA.
I cant seem to get it to carry out the loop section any ideas would be appreciated.
The script is used to write labels in ZPL with a StartNumber and EndNumber and the range between will print out on labels.

```
 'Wscript.Echo ZPLText
 ObjZebra.Write(ZPLText)

'Loop Counter

 StartNumber = StartNumber + 1

'Loop Condition

Loop Until StartNumber > 0 + EndNumber

 Wscript.sleep 500
 objZebra.Close
 Set objZebra = Nothing
End If
End If
Loop

End Function
```

Comment: that is not VB.NET code.  VB.NET is not VBscript

Comment: Excuse my lack of detail but in the HTA I have the script set as: <script language="VBScript">

Comment: ...so remove the VB.NET tag and add VBScript to attract the right attention

Comment: Apologies didn't see the full tag corrected

Comment: Now you can format your code properly. 4 spaces at the beginning of a line make it code formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still ill formatted. And it doesn't use proper syntax either.
I suggest you get a copy of [script56.chm contained in scrdocen.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe) (as long it is possible). and look at the `do .. loop` :

Repeats a block of statements while a condition is True or until a condition becomes True.

```
Do [{While | Until} condition]
   [statements]
   [Exit Do]
   [statements]
Loop
```

Or, you can use this syntax:

```
Do
   [statements]
   [Exit Do]
   [statements]
Loop [{While | Until} condition]
```